# How to mock original XML output to use in test class in Java?

Tags: java, xml, junit, mockito, document

I am writing Junit test cases for an Application and again and again I have to build dummy `Document object` and set root element and every other elements according to my original response so as to pass in my `Mockito.when(m1()).thenReturn(respDoc)`. The code is something like this

`Code Starts`

```
Document respDoc = new Document();
Element elem = new Element("RootElement");
respDoc.setRootElement(elem);
Element node1 = new Element("Nodes").addContent("FirstNode");
elem.add(node1);
 **And So On...**
```

`Code Ends`

Sometimes the response xml is so big that it takes all of my time just to create this `Document` object. Is there any way where I can just pass this whole `XML` and it gives me the desired output.

Please let me know if theres any confusion.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is a custom library as you stated, no one can help.  You will need to probably make a method that consumes your String XML and is smart to create a Document for you.

Comment: Yupp got it thanks. Actually we have SAXBuilder and i can use that. Thanks again for your answer. It gave me what I needed.

Comment: no worries, hope it helps

Comment: Meanwhile can you also help me with how can I achieve this if i dont want to use another external file? Like can i put my XML obj as String and then can I pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Document` is from JDOM Library:

You need the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you parse it:

```
  import org.jdom2.Document;
  import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;


  String FILENAME = "src/main/resources/staff.xml";

  SAXBuilder sax = new SAXBuilder();

  Document doc = sax.build(new File(FILENAME));

  Mockito.when(m1()).thenReturn(doc);
```

Reference: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/

---

Well the documentation states you can use an InputStream:

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html
Example:

```
String yourXmlString = "<xml>";

InputStream stringStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourXmlString .getBytes("UTF-8"));

SAXBuilder sax = new SAXBuilder();
 
Document doc = sax.build(stringStream );
```

Comment: Actually my document is of type `msjava.hdom.Document`

Comment: What library is that @SauravSrivastav

Comment: Actually its customised library of the company where i work

Comment: Then sorry you will have to look into your library code and see if there is a builder of some kind, that takes a String or not.